# Including and ID and Parent ID in Powershell File Inventory

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that performs and inventory of a fileshare.  I want to know how to add ID to each line in the csv file and also a parent ID to line in the csv.

I am new to Powershell but worked out how to get the inventory script working.
Here is the code.

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$SourcePath = "G:\My Drive"

$DestinationCSVPath = "e:\G Drive Inventory 20180611.csv" #Destination for Temp CSV File
$CSVColumnOrder = 'Path', 'IsDIR', 'Directory', 'FileCount', 'Parent', 'Name', 'CreationTime', 'LastAccessTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'Extension', 'BaseName', 'B'
#, 'Root', 'IsReadOnly', 'Attributes', 'Owner', 'AccessToString', 'Group' #, #'MD5', #'SHA1' #Order in which columns in CSV Output are ordered

#FOLDERS ONLY
#$SourcePathFileOutput = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse  | where {$_.PSIsContainer} 

#FILES AND FOLDERS
$SourcePathFileOutput = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse  #| where {$_.PSIsContainer} #Uncomment for folders only


$HashOutput = ForEach ($file in $SourcePathFileOutput) {
    Write-Output (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Path = $file.FullName
        IsDIR = $file.PSIsContainer
        Directory = $File.DirectoryName
        FileCount = (GCI $File.FullName -Recurse).Count
        Parent = $file.Parent
        Name = $File.Name
        CreationTime = $File.CreationTime
        LastAccessTime = $File.LastAccessTime
        LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
        Extension = $File.Extension
        BaseName = $File.BaseName
        B = $File.Length

        #Root = $file.Root
        #IsReadOnly = $file.IsReadOnly
        #Attributes = $file.Attributes
        #Owner = $acl.owner
        #AccessToString = $acl.accesstostring
        #Group = $acl.group
        #MD5 = Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
        #SHA1 = Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
    }) | Select-Object $CSVColumnOrder
}


$HashOutput | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $DestinationCSVPath
```

I want to know how to add ID to each line in the csv file and also a parent ID to line in the csv.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you mean by `ID`... Can you elaborate on that and perhaps give us an example of the desired output?

Comment: Assigning a unique ID to each result, and also then calculating a parent.  For example C:\files, ID 1, ParentID 0, C:\Files\Folder ID 2, ParentID 1 etc as it goes generates its listing, along with all the other calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
$ID=1
$SourcePath="c:\temp"

$SourcePathFileOutput=@()

#for have the parent dir
$SourcePathFileOutput += Get-Item $SourcePath | %{
$ParentPath=if ($_.PSIsContainer){$_.parent.FullName}else{$_.DirectoryName}

Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value ($ID++)
Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PARENTPATH" -Value $ParentPath
$_
}

#for have all directory and file
$SourcePathFileOutput += Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | %{
$ParentPath=if ($_.PSIsContainer){$_.parent.FullName}else{$_.DirectoryName}

Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ID" -Value ($ID++)
Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PARENTPATH" -Value $ParentPath
$_
}

#List dir for optimise 
$DirOutput=$SourcePathFileOutput | where {$_.psiscontainer}

#for output result (add all properties you want)
$list=foreach ($Current in $SourcePathFileOutput)
{
$Result=[pscustomobject]@{
    Path = $Current.FullName
    PARENTPATH=$Current.PARENTPATH
    ISDIR=$Current.psiscontainer
    ID=$Current.ID
    PARENTID=($DirOutput | where {$_.FullName -eq $Current.PARENTPATH}).ID
}

#Initialise parent root
if ($Result.PARENTID -eq $null) {$Result.PARENTID=0}

#send result on output
$Result
} 

$list | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
#Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$SourcePath = "G:\My Drive"

$DestinationCSVPath = "e:\G Drive Inventory 20180611.csv" #Destination for Temp CSV File
$CSVColumnOrder = 'Path', 'IsDIR', 'Directory', 'FileCount', 'Parent', 'Name', 'CreationTime', 'LastAccessTime', 'LastWriteTime', 'Extension', 'BaseName', 'B','ID','ParentID'
#, 'Root', 'IsReadOnly', 'Attributes', 'Owner', 'AccessToString', 'Group' #, #'MD5', #'SHA1' #Order in which columns in CSV Output are ordered

#FOLDERS ONLY
#$SourcePathFileOutput = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse  | where {$_.PSIsContainer} 

#FILES AND FOLDERS
$SourcePathFileOutput = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath -Recurse | Sort-Object Fullname #| where {$_.PSIsContainer} #Uncomment for folders only

$CurrentID = 1
$IDs = [ordered]@{}
$IDs.add(($SourcePathFileOutput[0].fullname | split-path),0)

$HashOutput = ForEach ($file in $SourcePathFileOutput) {
    $IDs.add($file.fullname,$CurrentID)
    Write-Output (New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    ID = $CurrentID
    ParentID = $IDs.$($file.fullname | split-path)
    Path = $file.FullName
    IsDIR = $file.PSIsContainer
    Directory = $File.DirectoryName
    FileCount = (GCI $File.FullName -Recurse).Count
    Parent = $file.Parent
    Name = $File.Name
    CreationTime = $File.CreationTime
    LastAccessTime = $File.LastAccessTime
    LastWriteTime = $File.LastWriteTime
    Extension = $File.Extension
    BaseName = $File.BaseName
    B = $File.Length        
    #Root = $file.Root
    #IsReadOnly = $file.IsReadOnly
    #Attributes = $file.Attributes
    #Owner = $acl.owner
    #AccessToString = $acl.accesstostring
    #Group = $acl.group
    #MD5 = Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
    #SHA1 = Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm SHA1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
    }) | Select-Object $CSVColumnOrder
    $CurrentID++
}


$HashOutput | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $DestinationCSVPath
```

**Explanation:**

I piped `$SourcePathFileOutput` to `Sort-Object` because it is easiest to assign an ordered ID if things are sorted by their location in the directory tree.

`$CurrentID` starts at 1 because the first item in the loop is not the root parent. Your loop will increment this variable by 1 (`$CurrentID++`) at the end of each loop iteration so that the next file/directory will a new number. Since this code creates `$CurrentID` as an `Int32` type, you will have issues if you have more than 2 billion files/directories. You will have to initialize it as a 64-bit type (`$CurrentID = [long]1`). However, I believe there can only be Int32 number of keys in a hash table, so a different strategy will need to be adopted if you have billions of files.

`$IDs` is a ordered hash table that tracks IDs for all files and directories. Each key in hash table is the path to the current item in the loop. The value is the ID assignment. This means you can access the ID using the syntax `$IDs.path`. After the initialization, I added the first entry with ID 0, which represents the root parent.

Inside of the loop, I created the `ID` property that just stores the current value of `$CurrentID`. I created 'ParentID', which looks up the parent directory inside of the `$IDs` hash table and returns that key's ID value.

I updated `$CSVColumnOrder` to have the `ID` and `ParentID` as columns.

You could have the ID scheme be slightly different if you do your initial sort differently. You don't have to increment by 1. You may have a requirement that you want directories to have smaller IDs than files and that will require more code (I did not see this requirement though).

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings.  I get this error, any ideas? - Fileshare inventory.ps1:20 char:40
+     $IDs.add($file.fullname,$CurrentID)
+                                        ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At C:\Users\User\fileshare inventory.ps1:20 char:40
+     $IDs.add($file.fullname,$CurrentID)
+                                        ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral

Comment: @CameronStewart I updated the code to fix that problem.